# Restrict the predictions from SGDRegressor in scikit-learn to positive values

Tags: scikit-learn

I am working on a knowledge problem in Kaggle whose labels are positive numbers. I tried using SGDRegressor in scikit-learn to train and test the model. However, some of the predictions from the learnt model are negative.

Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to restrict the predictions from a regressor like SGD (within scikit learn) to have only positive values. I am aware of brute force techniques to cap the values after I get the prediction, but I do not keen on following this approach as it will not represent the true model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to fit on `z = np.log(y)` instead of `y`: `model = SGDRegressor(**params).fit(X_train, np.log(y_train))` and then `y_predicted = np.exp(model.predict(X_test))`.

You can subclass `SGDRegressor` to overload the `fit` and `predict` method to do this change of target variable internally if you want to be able to use sklearn's `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV` tools on such a model

Comment: Maybe `z = log(1 + y)` and `y_pred = exp(z_pred) - 1` if you have zero values in `y`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I understand the first part of your solution, i.e. log transformation of y or 1+y. However, could you kindly elaborate or point me to an example for the second part where we can subclass the SGDRegressor to overload the fit and predict method. I am new to ML and scikit-learn - so any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I am just saying that tf you don't want to wrap boiler plate code to do the transform manually over and over you can factorize it in a class and you can do so by implementing a class that follows the sklearn conventions: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects this will make it possible to use it with cross validation tools.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear! I really appreciate it. Also, sorry I am not able to up-vote your answer as I do not have enough reps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I just found it after searching based on having the same experience as the original post.  I tried the answer given, which I could not get to work with my data.  After working on this further, I was able to get the SGDRegressor to work (i.e., give positive predictions that were well-fit to my data) after scaling the columns in my X...

```py
# add to imports
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# add to code before training SGDRegressor model
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
Xs = scaler.transform(X)

# I used train_test_split, so I changed first parameter from X to Xs
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xs, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=26)

# train model
sgd = linear_model.SGDRegressor()
sgd.fit(X_train, y_train)

# test model
y_predicted = sgd.predict(X_test)
```

Prior to adding the parts for scaling the inputs, I was getting all negative predictions, even though y (train and test) were all positive.  After adding the scaling, y_predicted were all positive numbers and very close to y_test [granted I created y for this data based on X, so I was expecting good performance].  Posting this answer in case it helps anyone else.

For Documentation visit [HERE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).